How can I disable git automatic rename for azure pull requests
In our repository we have several small files with identical content. When one is removed from /foo/bar and one is added to /bar/foo these are wrongly shown as merge conflicts in Azure pull requests. How can one disable the git automatic rename detection for Azure pull requests? It's straightforward to do it with git config for a repository but in this case I don't have access to the repository as it's hosted in Azure.

Please describe in detail what you mean by "disable git automatic rename for azure pull requests". It would be better to add some screenshots to help clarify.

You mean stop using the name of the pull request as the merge commit message?

I agree we need more context to be sure, but my best guess as to what is being asked, is: the Pull Request is showing a delete plus an add as a rename, presumably because the contents of the new file are very similar to the deleted file, and OP would prefer the rename to instead show up as a separate add and delete.

@TTT you're absolutely correct

The update helps a lot, particularly "merge conflicts". You're asking the wrong question here, and due to that I struggled in deciding whether to upvote or downvote (or neither), but eventually landed on upvote because IMHO it's an example of a good question that happens to be an X-Y problem (though some might argue it's not possible to have an X-Y problem also be a good question). I also added an answer explaining what I mean by this.

This is a wonderful example of an X-Y problem!
Your problem is:

You have a Pull Request in Azure DevOps that has merge conflicts.

But these aren't just any old conflicts. They are caused because you have an "add/delete" conflict for different files and it's only showing as a conflict because the file content is identical, and Git is incorrectly assuming this is a file rename. Git is obviously wrong here.
Since your Pull Request conflict is with Azure DevOps, and it's caused by Git's automatic rename detection, this led you to ask:

How can I disable git automatic rename for azure pull requests?

Your motivation is clear, but the answer to that specific question is (AFAIK), "You can't."
But the real question is,

What can I do when I have these specific types of conflicts?

And the answer to that is....[suspense building]

Resolve the conflict the same way you would any other conflict.

Update your feature branch how you normally would for a regular conflict via merge or rebase, push or force push your feature branch, and the PR will auto-update without a merge conflict.

That would work well in a small team of software developers. But this will be deployed to  large team of function developers who knows very little about version management. They don't even write code, they commit files created in a graphical tool. So just presenting them with this behavior and expect them to solve it will yield a fair amount of confusion and version management errors in the organization...

@user2052153 If you use Git and you have conflicts you need to resolve them. You can avoid having conflicts by making sure feature branches are up to date when starting work, and updating (and resolving) them before creating a PR. For the specific type of conflict you mentioned, if it's happening often, you can probably write a script to resolve it automatically.
